# В чём причина двойного переопределения некоторых css-правил в reset.css?

Tags: css

В данном вопросе речь идёт о наборе CSS-правил `reset.css`, написанных Eric Meyer:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Тут два наложения:

1. `font: inherit;` перезаписывает `font-size: 100%;`
2. `content: none` перезаписывает `content: ''`.

Вроде бы мелочь, но в продвинутых IDE, отслеживающих качество кода, эти перезаписи будут мозолить глаза таким вот образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если старые версии IE не поддерживает `inherit` для `font`, то почему нельзя ограничиться просто `font-size: 100%;`? А что касается `content`, то пустые кавычки вроде как поддерживаются везде, где поддерживаются псевдоэлементы `:after` и `:before`, потому в `none` необходимости нет.

Comment: Поддержка старых браузеров?

Comment: @andreymal Добавил абзац в конец вопроса по данному поводу.